# Can GHCi perform substitutions in `:type <expr>` commands?

Tags: haskell, ghci

GHCi has `:type <expr>` to show the type of an expression:

```
Prelude> :t (<*>)
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Can GHCi show the result after a substitution of any of the type variables? For example, let `f = ((->) c)`, then

```
:t (<*>) ::  ((->) c) (a->b) -> ((->) c) a -> ((->) c) b
(<*>) ::  ((->) c) (a->b) -> ((->) c) a -> ((->) c) b
  :: (c -> a -> b) -> (c -> a) -> c -> b
```

Is there a way to let GHCi work out these substitutions?

Comment: Have you tried using [`TypeApplications`](https://kseo.github.io/posts/2017-01-08-visible-type-application-ghc8.html)?

Comment: @AJFarmar What, if any, is the syntax for a partial application of a type constructor? `:t (<*>) @Maybe` works, but things like `Either a` or `((->) r` contain undefined type variables.

Comment: @chepner You can use holes for that. `(<*>) @(Either _)`, `(<*>) @((->) _)`. What if you want two holes that are the same type? For that one I'm not sure...

Comment: Is there a version of Haskell that supports named type holes, or am I thinking of Idris (or maybe Agda)?

Comment: @chepner I don't know of such a thing for Haskell, so I suspect you're thinking of another language.

Comment: @chepner That sounds like agda to me.

Comment: I have a cunning plan for emulating named type holes in GHC. Imagine I want to ask `:t id @(a -> a)`. I make a new type alias, `type Tmp a = a -> a`. Then I ask `:t id @(Tmp _)`. This works (and is generalizable to other named-type-hole situations), but the result has `Tmp` applications un-expanded, which is a bit unfortunate...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there are a few ways. Many operations make their type variables a part of their API, and you can observe this by turning on the right options and asking in the right way.

```
> :set -fprint-explicit-foralls 
> :t +v (<*>)
(<*>)
  :: forall (f :: * -> *).
     Applicative f =>
     forall a b. f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

This actually doesn't look that special, but says something important: because the `forall`d type variables are not enclosed in braces, they can be the subject of type applications. (But you should trust the "braces"/"not braces" distinction *only* in `:t +v` queries! Normal `:t` munges type-application-availableness in a brittle way that may change from GHC version to GHC version.)

```
> :set -XTypeApplications
> :t (<*>) @((->) _)
(<*>) @((->) _)
  :: forall {w} {a} {b}. (w -> a -> b) -> (w -> a) -> w -> b
```

Sometimes you will find a term where you cannot use type applications in this way. For example:

```
> :t +v \f x -> f <*> x
\f x -> f <*> x
  :: forall {f :: * -> *} {a} {b}.
     Applicative f =>
     f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Here the braces indicate that there are no types available for type application. Are we out of luck? No, we can still use type holes to fill in only the parts we care about and ask GHC about the rest.

```
> :set -XPartialTypeSignatures
> :set -Wno-partial-type-signatures
> :t (\f x -> f <*> x) :: ((_ -> _) -> _)
(\f x -> f <*> x) :: ((_ -> _) -> _)
  :: forall {w} {a} {b}. (w -> a -> b) -> (w -> a) -> w -> b
```